# Erro na consulta linq

Tags: c#, linq, sql-select, entity-framework-6

Estou tentando fazer uma consulta na tabela abaixo, da minha base de dados.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Esta consulta é realizada através do método abaixo:

```cs
public void compraAcoes(float cepf, string codigo, int quantidade)
{
    string cd = codigo;
    try
    {
        float cpf;
        BuscaNet busca = new BuscaNet();
        Cotacao objeto = new Cotacao();

        objeto = busca.buscaInformacao(codigo);
        cpf = cepf;
        string empresa = objeto.empresa;
        string tipo = objeto.tipo;
        DateTime data = Convert.ToDateTime(objeto.data);
        string hora = objeto.hora;
        double abertura = objeto.abertura;
        double maxima = objeto.maxima;
        double minima = objeto.minima;
        double media = objeto.media;
        double fechamento = objeto.fechamento;
        double fechamento_anterior = objeto.fechamento_anterior;
        Int32 volume = objeto.volume;
        Int32 volume_financeiro = objeto.volume_financeiro;
        Int32 negocio = objeto.negocio;
        double oferta_de_compra = objeto.oferta_de_compra;
        double oferta_de_venda = objeto.oferta_de_venda;
        Int32 quantidade_ofertada_compra = objeto.quantidade_ofertada_compra;
        Int32 quantidade_ofertada_venda = objeto.quantidade_fertada_venda;
        double variação = objeto.variacao;
        string status = objeto.status;
        string fase = objeto.fase;     

        string cod = codigo;
        bancotccEntities bc = new bancotccEntities();

        var ac = from obj in bc.acao
                 where (obj.cpf == cepf && obj.codigo == cod)
                 select obj; 

        if (ac == null)
        {
            double vatotal_acao;         
            vatotal_acao = (quantidade * fechamento);
            banco.inserirAcao(cepf, cod, empresa, tipo, data, hora, abertura, maxima, minima, media, fechamento, fechamento_anterior, volume, volume_financeiro, negocio,
                      oferta_de_compra, oferta_de_venda, quantidade_ofertada_compra, quantidade_ofertada_venda, variação, status, fase);
            banco.inserirCarteira(cepf, cod, fechamento, quantidade, vatotal_acao);
        }
        else
        {          
            carteira ca = bc.carteira.FirstOrDefault(obj => obj.cpf == cepf && obj.codigo == cod);
            //int qt = ca;
            ca.qtdacao = ca.qtdacao + quantidade;
            //int nova_quant = ca.qtdacao + quantidade;
            // int nova_quant = ca.qtdacao;
            double valor =  quantidade * fechamento;
            ca.vtotalacao = ca.vtotalacao + valor;
            //double novo_valor = ca.vtotalacao;
            banco.atualizaAcao(cepf, codigo, empresa, tipo, data, hora, abertura, maxima, minima, media, fechamento, fechamento_anterior,
                 volume, volume_financeiro, negocio, oferta_de_compra, oferta_de_venda, quantidade_ofertada_compra,
                 quantidade_ofertada_venda, variação, status, fase);

            // banco.atualizarCarteira(cepf, cod, fechamento, qt, total_acao);
            //  banco.atualizarCarteira(cpf, codigo, fechamento, quantidade, novo_valor);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        throw new Exception(e.Message.ToString());
    }
    /*catch (DbEntityValidationException dbEx)
    {
        foreach (var validationErrors in dbEx.EntityValidationErrors)
        {
            foreach (var validationError in validationErrors.ValidationErrors)
            {
                Trace.TraceInformation("Property: {0} Error: {1}", validationError.PropertyName, validationError.ErrorMessage);
            }
        }
    }*/
}
```

---

O método  verifica se os dados existem, se não existirem ele insere, esta parte já testei e esta funcionando, o problema esta quando ele possui dados no banco. Tento buscar os valores qdacao e vtotalacao, mas o select que estou usando não esta devolvendo nenhum valor conforme a figura abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

me devolvendo o erro:

> Referência de objeto não definida para uma instância de um objeto.

Já tentem fazer o select conforme o código abaixo mas apenas troca o erro:

```cs
var ca = (from obj in bc.carteira
                           where (obj.cpf == cepf && obj.codigo == cod)
                           select  obj).First();
```

> A sequência não contém elementos

Podem me ajudar?

Comment: O erro é claro em dizer que você está tentando pegar o primeiro elemento de uma lista que não possui resultados. Quais são os valores que estão sendo passados em `cepf` e `codigo`?

Comment: Os valores de cepf e código são recebidos por parâmetro de outra classe. public void compraAcoes(float cepf, string codigo, int quantidade) nesse caso os valores são: 98765500000  e PETR4.
        {

Comment: Ainda acho que é um problema de parametrização. Possivelmente os valores passados para o `FirstOrDefault` são diferentes dos das colunas que você está tentando selecionar.

Comment: Este select  não esta buscando o primeiro objeto no banco que aceite a clausula where?

Comment: A query que está a fazer está a procura do primeiro elemento (First) que iguale a condição passada ou no entanto, se não existir nenhum elemento, é devolvido `null` (OrDefault). Portanto como o @CiganoMorrisonMendez mencionou, o problema está no `Where`. Coloque as variáveis que está a usar para fazer a comparação no `watch`, confirme que são as esperadas ou que efectivamente existem na BD.

Comment: ok pessoal entendi. alguém sabe como faço para que e devolva do banco os itens que preciso?  qtdacao e vtotalacao? ou tenho que fazer isso em outra pergunta?

Comment: @user9090, quando você debug qual o valor antes acima na variavel cepf e cod, pelo visto isso é o o que está acontecendo de não trazer os dados corretamente, em relação a segunda questão seria: `var c = bc.cateira.Where(x => x.cpf == cepf && x.codigo == cod).Select(x => new { x.qtdacao, x.vtotalacao).FirstOrDefault()`

Comment: o valor de cod é PTR4, mas o valor de cepf  9.87655455E+10

Comment: Então você acaba de encontrar o problema, o cepf ta num formato diferente. Geralmente em cpf eu utilizo string (nvarchar, varchar), então nesse formato não vai encontrar o registro, entendeu? Na sua base tá 987654321 e no que ta mostrando tem um ponto depois do 9.8... por isso ratificando o valor ta diferente!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***Erro encontrado:***

No cepf a `variável` do tipo `long` ta `9.87655455E+10` diferente no que tá na base de dados, por isso, não é encontrado o registro que está `98765500000`, verifique porque o mesmo se encontra no formato diferente da base. Indico que coloque no campo `cpf` na sua tabela como `Varchar(11)` sendo mais tranquilo nesse caso o trabalho com `String` no código.

***Em relação a outra questão seria:***

```
var c = bc.cateira
    .Where(x => x.cpf == cepf && x.codigo == cod)
    .Select(x => new { x.qtdacao, x.vtotalacao })
    .FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: realmente não tinha percebido isso, vou modificar o banco e o código , valeu a força. o segundo tema na verdade era um outro select que tentei fazer para obter a solução.

Comment: @user9090, ok .....